# how to deactivate eqnarray environment in AUCTeX

Tags: environments, emacs, auctex

It is mentioned in several places that the environment `eqnarray` should be avoided, e.g., this [Avoid eqnarray!](https://tug.org/pracjourn/2006-4/madsen/madsen.pdf) article.

That said, when I am using AUCTeX in emacs, if I type `C-c C-e eq TAB`, I would get the cycling between `eqnarray`, `eqnarray*`, `equation`, and `equation*`. How can I turn off this `eqnarray` related prompt since it is not recommended? Note that I have the following in my `.emacs` file

```
  (if (>= emacs-major-version 24)
  (setq completion-cycle-threshold 5))
```

I guess that I could dig through the `.el` file somewhere and comment out the related lines. On the other hand, I am hoping that this should be done by just adding a few lines in the `.emacs` file. Thanks in advance!

---

(2022.10) Recently I discovered that the problem can be bypassed by using some other nice emacs mode such as `ivy` or `vertico`. The modes will present a lot more choices, but remembers your recent ones.

The accepted answer is still valuable since it prevents users to even try `eqnarray` etc. As it will not appear in the choice list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would have to edit `latex.el`, but as you said, not the best choice.

Not heavily tested, but putting this into your init file should do the trick:

```lisp
(defun dj/remove-eqnarray ()
  "Remove eqnarray*? from variable `LaTeX-environment-list'."
  (let ((evil-envs '("eqnarray" "eqnarray*")))
    (LaTeX-environment-list)
    (dolist (env evil-envs)
      (setq LaTeX-environment-list
            (assq-delete-all
             (car (assoc env LaTeX-environment-list))
             LaTeX-environment-list)))))

(eval-after-load "latex"
  '(progn
     (dj/remove-eqnarray)
     (add-hook 'TeX-auto-cleanup-hook #'dj/remove-eqnarray t)))
```