# Editing the list of environment autocompletion in AUCTeX

Tags: emacs, auctex

In Emacs the command `C-c C-e` prompts for an environment to insert. After pressing `TAB` I'd like to type just two letters `eq` and get `equation` or `equation*`, which I use most of the times. Unfortunately, there are another two "undesirable" environments `eqnarray` and `eqnarray*`, which I never use (in fact, they are even not recommended).

Of course, I can type three letters `equ` and get what I want, but this is really much slower: `e`, `q`, and `TAB` are so easy to type by one hand. My guess was to look into `latex.el` file for possible solutions: in that file I commented all lines with `eqnarray`, `eqnarray*`. In result, `C-c C-e` does not show `eqnarray*` but still shows `eqnarray`.

I have no idea what to do further. Maybe there are better solutions instead of editing `latex.el`?

I know that using YASnippets one can bind `eq` to `equation` and so on. In fact, I need to modify that list in order to be able to change one environment to another by `C-u C-C C-e`.

**Update**

Here is the [solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/320540/76063) proposed by ArashEsbati.

Comment: You should try out an autocompletion library like [helm](https://emacs-helm.github.io/helm/).

Comment: @gernot I wrote that it is not so convenient, you can press `e`, `q` `TAB` almost simultaneously by one hand. And, I do not know why, but unconsciously, for any environment I always type only first two letters, then press `TAB` and type another letter if I need. And I can't get rid of this habit.

Comment: Maybe [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/320540/76063) here helps.

Comment: @ArashEsbati That's exactly the solution that I wanted. But, unfortunately, Emacs gives me some error with that piece of code.

Comment: In Emacs, do `M-x toggle-debug-on-error RET`, trigger the error and update your question with the error(s) you get.  Otherwise it is not possible to see what is happening.

Comment: @ArashEsbati. Thanks, I've updated the question.

Comment: Sorry, can't reproduce what you describe; I tried it also with Emacs 24.5.  How did you install AUCTeX?  And how do you activate it?

Comment: @ArashEsbati Yes, I know. It is strange, but I've got this on two different machine. I installed AUCTeX via melpa. I am not sure what do you mean by activation. My first lines for AUCTeX in my init file are `(require 'tex-site)
(setq TeX-auto-save t)
(setq TeX-parse-self t)
(setq-default TeX-master nil)`

Comment: Comment the `(require 'tex-site)` line since it is not necessary when you install AUCTeX from ELPA, maybe that helps.

Comment: @ArashEsbati That didn't help, but following your idea I rewrote my latex init file, commenting some parts of it. After that it started to work. Thanks!

Comment: Glad you have it sorted out.  Maybe you could write an answer describing the culprit in your init file and how you fixed it.